LXD - How to resize "default" zfs storage pool?
I am using lxd to host a windows 11 VM and followed this guide to setup.
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-a-windows-11-vm-using-lxd#4-install-windows
The storage pool i created uses the zfs file system, has a size of 128GiB and is named 'default'.
When creating the Windows 11 VM, I gave it a volume of 128GiB also, using all available space within the ZFS storage pool.
Now I want to create a snapshot, which i understand is stored in the same 'default' pool.
I assume, I need to resize (expand) the 'default' pool.
How do I do this?
Thanks!
USER@SERVERNAME:~$ lxc storage show default
name: default
description: ""
driver: zfs
status: Created
config:
  size: 128GiB
  source: /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/disks/default.img
  zfs.pool_name: default
used_by:
- /1.0/instances/win11
- /1.0/profiles/default
locations:
- none


Just execute lxc storage set default size=200GiB or to whatever size you may need.
Use lxc storage show default to verify your changes.
Note that the physical size of the loopback disk will not increase until the space is needed. You can check its current size with the command sudo zpool list.
